# Fetch Latest record which is having greater than 1

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table like

```
Group ID    Group No    Text Desc 
123A45      081         Subscriber 
123A46      083         Provider
123C48      081         Consumer
123B76      054         Worker
123B77      066         Player
```

In the above case I need to get Text Desc as Provider for the Group ID  123A45 and Player as text desc for the Group ID 123B76 because the Group ID is the next number of the previous number

RESULT :-

```
Group ID  Group No   Text Desc 
123A45       081      Provider
123B76       054      Player
```

I tried Max condition but it is not working

Comment: Fix your tags. Which server are you using? MySQL <> MSSQL. Please post your sample data in a readable format. I can't tell which column is which. A minimally reproduceable sample would go a long way here.

Comment: I removed the conflicting tags; please add the tag for the actual RDBMS you are using. For advice on how to improve your question see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: I'm using Sql serverResult should be
Group I'd - 12345 Groupno - 081  test desc - Provider
Group I'd - 12376 Groupno - 054 test desc - Player

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Research SQLServer Lead() function. Or self-join with calculation that adds 1 to Group.

Comment: GroupI'd  GroupNo    Text desc 
12345       081            Subscriber 
12346        083            Provider
12348        081            Consumer
12376        054            Worker
12377        066            Player

Comment: June7 Can u give in query

Comment: Edit your question to show essential details such as desired output.

Comment: I'm not even sure you can say "Add 1 to Group ID", because what happens when the IDs aren't sequential?  For example, in the sample data, there's a gap between 12348 and 12376.

Comment: Correct, some records will not have match. Which is what the OP narrative seems to indicate is desired.

Comment: We should compare the Id's if the next I'd is exactly the addition of 1 else we can leave......if it is a number we can take group I'd + 1 what else if it is string like 123A45 how to add 1 to it ?

Comment: Well, if there are alpha characters, that really throws a wrench in the works. Again, edit your question to show representative data and desired output.

Comment: Changed the I'd to String format

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work:

```
SELECT
  A.GroupID, 
  A.GroupNo,
  B.TextDesc
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT 
     GroupID - 1 AS GID,
     TextDesc
   FROM Table1) B
  ON A.GroupID = B.GID
```

Edit per OP revised info:

```
SELECT A.GroupID, A.GroupNo, B.TextDesc 
FROM Data AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT Left(GroupID,4) & Right(GroupID,2) - 1 AS GID, TextDesc 
            FROM Data) AS B
ON A.GroupID = B.GID;
```

Comment: Or use LEFT JOIN if want to return all records.

Comment: Have to use a different alias name for GroupID field in the subquery to not get circular reference error.

Comment: And -1 instead of +1 returns desired output. If GroupID structure deviates in any way from given example, this will fail.